# Type mismatch error when assinging CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application") result to variable

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, createobject

I've tried to run Power Point application from VBA code in Excel module. I've selected Microsoft Power Point Object Library first. But when I run the code below I got an

> error 13 (Type mismatch)

in line with CreateObject function. I've noticed that the same case is trying to define other variables Ppp, Spp and Chrt. Do you know what could be the reason of the error?

```
    Sub Test()
      Dim App As PowerPoint.Application
      Dim Ppp As PowerPoint.Presentation
      Dim Spp As PowerPoint.Slide
      Dim Chrt As PowerPoint.Chart

      'Opens Power Point application
      Set App = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
      'Set App = New PowerPoint.Application
      'Makes the application visible (if necessary)
      App.Visible = True
      'Opens existing power point document
      Set Ppp = App.Presentations.Open("C:\Gap\Charts.pptx")
      'Sets the second slide
      Set Spp = Ppp.Slides(2)
      'Sets the chart named "EmbededChart"
      Set Chrt = Spp.Shapes("EmbededChart").Chart
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Set App = New PowerPoint.Application`

Comment: You're already referencing the PowerPoint type library, there's no need to `CreateObject`, just `New` up an instance of it.

Comment: With that line you suggest I've got another run-time error number -214xxxxxxx (This interface is not handled). And what is bizarre. When I am building a code (same way) to run Excel application from Power Point module, everythink is ok.